# A char between two ASCII values Java

Tags: java, char, ascii

I am a beginner at Java and I am currently writing a code where all the char symbols are printed out the same but the letters are printed out differently. How is it possible to exclude the ASCII values for the symbols? Is it possible to do something like this (where the values such as 32 and 64 represent the ASCII values corresponding to the characters) :

```
char notLetter = (originalMessage.charAt(i));

     if ((32 <= notLetter <= 64) || (91 <= notLetter <= 96) || (123 <= notLetter <= 126)){
       codedMessage += notLetter;
}
```

Or is there a simpler way to do it ? Thanks

Edit: when i try this code, I get the following error: "<= cannot be applied to boolean, int"

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly what you are asking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but casting a `char` to an `int` will give you the ASCII value and vice-versa.

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: how will that work?? `32 <= notLetter >= 64`  does this format actually works? and if so, shouldn't it be `32 <= notLetter <= 64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but here is some general information.

1. Use `char` literals like `'a'` rather than their `int` values. This makes programs much easier to follow.
2. You should use `StringBuilder` rather than string concatenation in most cases.
3. Java does not support expressions like `2 <= a <= 5`, so you have to do `2 <= a && a <= 5` instead.

The following code prints `, !`

```
String x = "Hello, World!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
    if (!(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char notLetter = (originalMessage.charAt(i));

     if ((32 <= notLetter  && notLetter   <= 64) || (91 <= notLetter  && notLetter <= 96) || (123 <= notLetter && notLetter<= 126)){
       codedMessage += notLetter;
}
```

try this.

`32 <= notLetter >= 64`

This won't work for 2 reasons:

1. The format is not supported.
2. A number that is greater than 32 and also greater than 64 is simply any number greater than 64

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Character Object Class, with the isAlphabetic() function:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)

ASCII and Unicode should match up.

Comment: I did, that was a typo. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

`32 <= notLetter >= 64` is not legal in java, but `32 <= notLetter && notLetter >= 64` is allowed.  However, that also will never be true — did you mean `32 <= notLetter && notLetter <= 64`?

One additional thing to note that may help you: you can actually use `<=` with a char on both sides:

```
(' ' <= notLetter && <= '@')
```

If I am understanding what you want to do, this will do what you want:

```
char notLetter = (originalMessage.charAt(i));

if ((' ' <= notLetter && notLetter <= '@') || ('[' <= notLetter && notLetter <= '`') || ('{' <= notLetter && notLetter <= '~')){
    codedMessage += notLetter;
}
```